What is the best way to create custom dynamic queries with pagination in native SQL
I'm using Spring Data JPA to replace JdbcTemplate. What's the best way to create custom dynamic queries with pagination in native SQL, for example, using @Query or EntityManager? Could you please provide some examples? Thank you

You can use @Query annotation from "org.springframework.data.jpa.repository" to write native SQL queries. You can check the example below that fetches the total number of rows in a customer table:
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer")
    long countTotalCustomers();

You can also use PageRequest from "org.springframework.data.domain" package to implement pagination.
Example:
repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));

The first parameter represents the start page and the second represents the page size.
